# Where to add programmatic constraints in UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, uiview

I have a custom UIView subclass called `CustomRectangle`. I instantiate this in a ViewController and create all of its constraints in a ViewController. My goal is to create all the constraints inside this UIView subclass programmatically. The problem is that I don't know how to set the constraints there because I don't have reference to any of the other views in the Storyboard.

For example, if I want my view `CustomRectangle` to be centered based on another view, I would create an `@IBOutlet` in the ViewController for the other view and then use that to center `CustomRectangle`. I don't know if this is possible to do in a UIView subclass.

I want to do this based on MVC (Model View Controller) architecture.

What is the best practice for this? Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: maybe you can override the method `didMoveToSuperview:` and create constraints there

Comment: How would I do that? I mean if i want to center my custom view called `CustomRectangle` based on another view, how is this done? I'm not sure how to architect this based on MVC.

Comment: in CustomRectangle  give constraints of your views

Comment: @PKT Not sure how. Could you give an example or tutorial? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use `initWithFrame` method of `CustomRectangle` to do this.

for emample in `UIView's Subclass`,

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

self = [super initWithFrame: frame];

if (self) {


    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    //add constraint here for example

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:50]];

}
return self;
}
```

Convert in swift this is objective c code!!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for responding! How do I set these constraints relative to other things? Not sure if I make sense. Basically,  if I want 'CustomRectangle' to be constrained to the bottom of a UIButton, I don't know how to get reference to that UIButton since everything is isolated in this UIView subclass.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should do:

1. Remember to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO for the constraints to work. However, if you think views autolayout way, inside your view you should use autolayout for your subviews, and the view that instantiates your view should add constraints to customRectangle (a.k.a widht, alignment, etc)
2. In the init method, you can just add constraints that only depend on your view. Other constraints should be added from outside.

For Example:

```
CustomRectangle *customRectangle = [[CustomRectangle *customRectangle alloc] init];
// just to be sure
customRectangle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
// just as an example
[self.view addConstraints[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:customRectangle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: When you say "Other constraints should be added from outside", could this be a `ViewController`? I am instantiating `CustomRectangle` in a `ViewController`, is this where I would put the constraints for it and if so, where would you put it, in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: It depends the approach you are using. For example, if your CustomRectangle is a subview of another View, you should do it in the init method of that View. If you are doing it inside a ViewController, it depends on the constraint, but probably the best place is in viewDidLoad.